# Finding all reachable nodes with neo4j

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

Having trouble with performance when searching for all reachable nodes.

I use javascript Neo4j driver.

I am using this cypher query:

```
START n = node({startNode})
MATCH n-[:CONNECTED_TO*]->e
RETURN DISTINCT(ID(e)) as id
```

Any alternative solutions?

PS. vertices are connected like this: (for 3x3)

[image]

for such connection but 11x11 i'm getting time of execution: 98609 ms

Comment: Which version are you running?

Comment: Here is a copy of your data model in the neo4j console. http://console.neo4j.org/r/y0tme7
I can't remember what this data structure is called, but essentially yes, when you grow large like 11x11, you're going to go down a lot of repetitive paths, which will chew up time. 98 seconds sounds like a lot of time, however if you cache the data, run the query a second time it will be faster.